CORS issue in Angular application when adding login step
I have a spring boot application that is set up with the auth0 login and the login is working when connecting directly through the browser. However, when adding the Angular front end application I have a CORS issue. I can see the redirect to the login page occuring :

When clicking the redirect link, if I am not logged in I can see the login page come up, however, if I am already logged in and I click that link I have the following page:

I have configured the CORS in auth0 to be able to allow my front end application. I have even tried to load the backend in a external server and contact the front end from another machine but still have this issue.
I can see the reply from the server with the redirect has the header Acess-Control-Allow-Origin set correctly with the value we need but I am not sure this header is being passed to the redirect call.
I have read somewhere that this can be because both server and front end are using localhost, is there a way to change this in either one of the applications?
Is there anything I am missing? Do I need to do an Interceptor in the front end angular that manually adds this header to the redirect?
Thanks in advance for the help.
EDIT:
In my spring-boot application this is my cors filter:
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class MyCORSFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
            "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

}

This is my application.yaml file with the auth0 configuration of the app:
spring:
  security:
   oauth2:
     client:
        registration:
          auth0:
            client-id: {ClientId}
            client-secret: {ClientSecret}
            scope: openid+profile+email
        provider:
          auth0:
            issuer-uri: {IssuerURI}

EDIT--------------------------------------------
ok so I started setting up the gateway and here is what I was able to do so far and unable to do:
Able - I can see that when I call a backend endpoint through the gateway I get redirected to the login page (I think backend redirect + externalLogin seems to be set up correctly);
Unable - When I connect my frontend app I still have this issue:

Here is the property file for my gateway:
server:
  port: 8096
spring:
   application:
      name: bff
   web:
    cors:
      allowed-origins: "http://localhost:4200"
      allowed-methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
      allowed-headers: Authorization,Content-Type
      allow-credentials: true 
      max-age: 3600
   cloud:
     gateway:
       routes:
         - id: frontend
           uri: http://localhost:4200
           predicates:
             - Path=/**
           filters:
             - RewritePath=/(?<segment>.*), /${segment}
         - id: backend
            uri: http://localhost:8090
           predicates:
             - Path=/api/**
           filters:
             - StripPrefix=1
           default-filters:
               - AddRequestHeader=Access-Control-Allow- 
               Origin,http://localhost:4200
               - AddResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow- 
               Origin,http://localhost:4200
               - AddResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow- 
               Methods,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS
               - AddResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow- 
               Headers,Authorization,Content-Type
               - AddResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials,true
   security:
     oauth2:
       client:
         registration:
           auth0:
             client-id: {id}
             client-secret: {secret}
             scope: openid+profile+email
             redirect-uri: {redirect-uri}
             authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
             client-authentication-method: basic
         provider:
           auth0:
             issuer-uri: {issuer}
             jwk-set-uri: {issuer-json}
             user-info-uri: {user-issuer}
       resourceserver:
         jwt:
         issuer-uri: {issuer}
         jws-algorithms:
            - RS512

I also added a CORS configuration class:
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

   @Bean
   public CorsWebFilter corsWebFilter() {
       CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration = new CorsConfiguration();
       corsConfiguration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
       corsConfiguration.addAllowedMethod("*");
       corsConfiguration.addAllowedHeader("*");
       corsConfiguration.setAllowCredentials(true);

       UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new 
       UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
       source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfiguration);

       return new CorsWebFilter(source);
    }
 }

A GatewayConfig
@Configuration
public class GatewayConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) 
    {
        return builder.routes()
              .route("backend_route", r -> r.path("/api/**")
                    .uri("http://localhost:8090"))  // Backend API URI
            .route("auth_route", r -> r.path("/login/oauth2/**")
                    .uri({issure})) 
            .build();
     }
  }

and a SecurityConfig class for the filterChain:
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

   @Bean
   public SecurityWebFilterChain 
   securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
       http
           .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
               .pathMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
               .anyExchange().authenticated()
           )
           .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
           .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
               .jwt(jwt -> 
         jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter()))
        )
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable()); 
    return http.build();
   }

@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri({issure-json}).build();
}


@Bean
public ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter 
 jwtAuthenticationConverter() {
    JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new 
  JwtAuthenticationConverter();
    jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(jwt -> 
  {
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = 
    jwt.getClaimAsStringList("roles").stream()
            .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role))   
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return authorities;
    });
    return new 
  ReactiveJwtAuthenticationConverterAdapter(jwtAuthenticationConverter);
} 

}
Anything I am doing wrong or missing?

please show your spring-boot security configuration, specifically CORS configuration

Done! Thanks for the help

You hid the URL you are calling but I am guessing it is not the spring boot app that returns the CORS error but rather the auth0 - see if you have the same issue as described here

Yes this seems to be the same issue, but last time I checked the post there is no fix for it provided by auth0 team or even a comment on it suggesting a work around. Do you know any possible solutions?

Theoretically you should be able to set it on auth0 website as suggested here, but if that doesn't work your only options would be 1) do all the calls to auth0 through your own local backend 2) Disable web security on chrome (not recommended and only solves the problem for you - not your users) 3) Switch away from auth0 (e.g. firebase, your own solution with keycloack, etc) since its auth0 lack of config that is the problem

Just a note that this line: response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));  Will allow cross-site requests from any domain.  There's a reason wildcards are not allowed for credentialed requests, and this will skirt around that.  (explicitly list the allowed domains)  For local testing, you can just turn off CORS rules in the browser, or use a proxy that keeps backend/frontend on same localhost port. (different ports are treated as different domains)

Thanks for the comments, how can I make all the auth() calls go through the backend? Do I need to set up a proxy for both ui and serve? Is there a simple way to do this @JAsgarov ?

@browsermator, Yes I realize this, and plan on changing it once I jhave this working. However, even if I leave it lile this auth0 has a subsection in the app definition to add CROS configs where I am assuming this is already filtered by the allowed URLs we set there but thanks for the reminder!

since you're running a Single-Page-App here, you should check this: https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/which-oauth-2-0-flow-should-i-use#is-the-client-a-single-page-app-

From what I understand, your Spring Security(Web)FilterChain is configured with both oauth2Login (authorization code flow driven by the Spring app what you call "login with the browser", which can produce the error screen you report) and oauth2ResourceServer (authorization code flow driven by the Angular app, with redirection between port 4200 on localhost and the authorization server) in the same filter-chain. If that's the case, this is a bad practice (even if many tutorials are built like that).
Your Angular app, like any single-page or mobile application, can't make a safe OAuth2 client: it can only be a "public" client, when it is recommended to use only "confidential" ones (clients running on your backend, which can keep a secret and immediately revoke a user session). For that reason, you should either:

configure your Spring REST API as a client (but this makes it stateful and, in case of multi-service architecture, you'll have as many clients to authorize as you have Spring applications)
introduce an OAuth2 BFF between your single page app and Spring REST API(s) configured as resource server(s) (much more scalable than REST APIs configured as clients with oauth2Login: only one stateful client to authorize, all downstream services being stateless)

In both cases, requests between Angular and the backend will be authorized with same-site session cookies (not Bearer tokens), which has several implications:

you need protection against CSRF (cookie-based so that the single-page or mobile application code can read the token and attach it to POST, PATCH, PUT, and DELETE requests)
you need the Angular app to have the same origin as the Spring backend: a session cookie should be flagged with same-site (which, of course, removes the need for any CORS configuration in Spring apps). This can be achieved:

by configuring the Angular "proxy" during development
with a reverse-proxy whatever the environment (dev & prod). When using spring-cloud-gateway as BFF (configured with oauth2Login and the TokenRelay filter), it can also be used as a reverse proxy for Angular assets (define a route for it).
by serving the Angular assets from the Spring OAuth2 client static resources (not as scalable as the reverse-proxy option)


in the authorization server allow requests from the Spring backend (CORS), and to it (allowed redirect URIs)
in the user agent in which the Angular app runs, instead of just following the redirection from the Spring client to the authorization server, start a new navigation.

For the last point, in the Spring client with oauth2Login, change the status of the authorization redirection from 302 to something in the 2xx range so that Angular can intercept it (observe the response) and "follow" by setting the window.location.href: "exit" the Angular app by initiating a new navigation to the authorization server (with an origin of its own => no CORS).
All that is detailed in my OAuth2 BFF article on Baeldung.

Hey thanks for the comment, I am very new to authentication and I am learning how to do it a bit as I go. Is there a way to create some sort of handler for the redirects in the backend so I avoid setting up a proxy or another server? Why is it that when I connect directly from the borwser (by calling the API directly like localhost:8080/endpoint I get redirected to the login page but when my frontend does it I have this CORS issue? Is there any way to turn off the CORS check on the angular app since both my backend + auth0 already handle this?

As I wrote in my answer, oauth2Login works with a same-site session cookie, which won't be exchanged with your Angular app unless it has the same origin. As also wrote in the answer, you may achieve that in dev with WebPack proxyConf (see Angular doc) and at runtime by serving Angular assets from static resources. In any case, you'll still have to hack the status of the authorization request redirection for Angular to follow by setting window.location.href and avoid some more CORS errors on the authorization server (Auth0 in your case).

I am following your article but I have some questions. So basically if I understand coorectly the set up for SpringSecurity using auth0 I did in my original API project is migrated to this one right? Also on step 4.6 the code for the loginOptions I have 2 issues, first SpringAddonsOidcProperties "cannot be resolved to a type" and second in new LoginOptionDto(label, loginUri, Objects.equals(clientAuthority, providerIssuerAuthority)); the objects import I can use are java.util.Objects or org.bouncycastle.util.Objects, both give errors in the method. Any dependncy I am missing?

There is a companion project on Github with the complete project (including dependencies, imports, and scripts to prepare all the infra in Docker). This project even has a Spring profile with the configuration for Auth0 (including the configuration of the required audience parameter on the authorization request)

Hey, I just created the gateway and added in the EDIT part of the post some new issues / steps I took, can you take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot for the help on this

"what I am doing wrong" confusing speed and haste. You apparently just skeemed my answer and article instead of taking the time to read (and understand) what is in there. You should not need CORS configuration at all in Spring: Angular and what is configured as a client with oauth2Login must have the same origin (and what is behind a gateway as this gateway as origin from the frontend point of view).

Also, as explained in the link in my answer 1st paragraph, you'll never read from me instructions to put oauth2Login and oauth2ResourceServer in the same Security(Web)FilterChain: this makes no sense at all.
